# RestFul Api Node.js & Mongoose: handling errors

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to create a restful API with Node.js, Express, MongoDB and Mongoose.

Schema, model and route are below:

```
// Schema
var OperatorSchema = new Schema({
    name : { type: String, unique: true , required: true},
    short_name : { type: String, unique:true, required: true },
});
Operator = mongoose.model('Operator', OperatorSchema);

// My Api for Operator
app.post('/api/operators', common.createOperator);
exports.createOperator = function(req, res){
    Operator.create(req.body, function (err, operator) {
        // If failed, return error message
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.send(404, err)
        }
        else {
            res.send(operator)
        }
    })
};
```

I have three questions:

**1 -** Handling error like that I found that the err object passed to the callback has a different structure depending if the error comes from mongoose or mongo.

```
// Mongo Error:
{
    "name": "MongoError",
    "err": "E11000 duplicate key error index: ussdauto.operators.$name_1  dup key: { : \"OpTest\" }",
    "code": 11000,
    "n": 0,
    "connectionId": 231,
    "ok": 1
}

// Mongoose Error:
{
    "message": "Validation failed",
    "name": "ValidationError",
    "errors": {
    "short_name": {
        "message": "Path `short_name` is required.",
        "name": "ValidatorError",
        "path": "short_name",
        "type": "required"
      }
    }
}
```

I don't want to expose all the details about errors: only a message explaining the error is enough, no need for to know if it's a mongoerror or a validationError for example. How do you manage it?

**2 -** The second question is more global: I'll have multiple API and each time I'll need to do the same work: check if there is errors, if some return via API in JSON the error message and if not continue normally. How can I use only one function to process errors and use it everywhere?

**3 -** I came from a python world (Django in fact) where Tastypie was a really great module which was handling all of that stuff itself. Do you know if such a module exists for Node.js + Express?

Comment: It works much better if you only ask one question per post.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Utils module with a function called processMongooseError(err) (or really w/e you fancy). You can then do a simple check in the function to figure out what type of error it is and then return a simple error message. I included an example of what I'm talking about below.

```
module.exports.processMongooseError = function(err) {
    if(err.name == "MongoError") {
        // mongo db error

    } else if(err.name == "ValidationError") {
        // mongoose error

    }
}
```

This module can be required wherever you need it and should solve your second question.

Answer (score 0):

In case this is still an issue, I faced the same problem, and used this mongoose plugin to have error messages be more consistent.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-beautiful-unique-validation

The plugin will take mongodb errors and convert them to mongoose like errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to display the full error response after a POST request to MongoDB you can use promises as a model to chain the response and display a custom content to users of your RESTFull API to a json response.

I will give you an example to serve as a good guide when building APIs:

1# Schema model ./api/models/operator

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const OperatorSchema = new Schema({
    name : { type: String, unique: true , required: true},
    short_name : { type: String, unique:true, required: true },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Operator', OperatorSchema);
```

2# Operator CRUD file, (POST) process ./api/routes/operator

```
// let's imagine that at this point you have already set up your form somewhere in your app and you are using body-parser, you have some Headers configuration for this route.


//import the libraries to execute your CRUD

const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');//generates json structure from incoming form post
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const Operators = require('../api/models/operators');

router.post('/api/operators', (req, res, next) => {

    const operator = new Operator({
        _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        name: req.body.name, //get the form field of "operator" using body-parser
        short_name: req.body.short_name // other fiels... from the Schema model
    }); // Build an object to store to the database using the schema set up

    // The following chain method returns a promise which you can build your custom responses for this post,
    // This chain method can be used for POST GET and DELETE requests 

    operator.save().then(result => {
        res.status(201).json({
            message: "Operator Created", //
            result: result // the "result" object can be filtered or you can simply return the message
        });

        // THE RESULT OBJECT PROPERTIES YOU CAN FILTER ON RETURN
        //  "result" : {
        //      name: "some operator name",
        //      short_name: "short guy",
        //      __v : 0,
        //      _id : "mongodb-id-generated"
        // }

    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({
            error: err 
        });
    });

}); // #### POSTS NEW OPERATORS
```

I use this process for quite some time and it's quite efficient to allow devs posting content to an API and if they get errors I show them what's necessary for them to elaborate their requests much better.

Answer (score -1):

```
"short_name": {
        "message": "Path `short_name` is required.",
```

This error is because,  in your schema this field is required

```
var OperatorSchema = new Schema({
    name : { type: String, unique: true , required: true},
    short_name : { type: String, unique:true, required: true },
```

while you are not giving any input via form or postman app.. you cannot leave required field blank.

I dont know anything that tell you what module causing error
but you can definitely guess just by looking at error.

```
"name": "MongoError",
    "err": "E11000 duplicate key error
```

This error is because you defined name as unique, but trying to inserting the same again.